# Is it possible to use a binding in md-component-id in md-sidenav?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using an md-sidenav in a directive. I want this to be a reusable component with the possibility of one on either side. I have a close and open button in the directive:

```
$mdSidenav($scope.header).close()
$mdSidenav($scope.header).open()
```

If I then hard code the md-component-id name in the sidenav so it matches $scope.header:

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="Tasks">
```

Then the above works, but I want it to be flexible:

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="{{header}}">
```

and this does not work. Perhaps this is a feature request for angular material to support this? Are there any simple workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine. [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DtjGakyo0slu5UtLvxnu?p=preview) (using Angular 1.4, angular-material 0.8.3)

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="init()">
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="{{header}}">
  <h2>
    <span>Value of $scope.header: </span>
    <span ng-bind="header"></span>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    <span>Value of md-component-id on sidenav: </span>
    <span ng-bind="md_component_id"></span>
  </h2>
</md-sidenav>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module 'App'
  .controller 'AppController', ($scope, $timeout) ->
    $scope.header = 'test'

    $scope.init = ->
      $timeout ->
        $scope.md_component_id = angular.element('md-sidenav').attr('md-component-id')
      , 500
```